# How to call jQuery AJAX on click event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I made a jQuery model.

Am trying to populate data using AJAX inside that model.

I am getting an id and using that I want to populate data using AJAX.

How should I call AJAX on click event?

Is there any other event when the model is opened or loaded?

The model is just the showing and hiding of div.

Comment: Which modal plugin? Jquery-ui modal? if so that does have an open event. Need clarification

Comment: Also..what does getting an id mean. Where are you getting it, from what, in what event - show us some code to give context...read Jon Skeets advice on how to ask a question http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: $('a.pop').click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
    var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define 

    $.get("content.php", { ref:id},function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: "+data );
    } );


i want to call that ajax file on this click event. how to do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply using:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.pop').click(function() { 
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.get('content.php', { ref:popID }, function(data) {
       $(popID+'Container').html(data);
       $(popID).dialog();
       alert('Load was performed.');
    });
    return false; // prevent default
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="example" class="flora" title="This is my title">
    I'm in a dialog!
    <div id="exampleContainer"></div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="clickingEvent" class="pop" rel="example">click to launch</a>
```

It is not tested, but as I see it, it should work...

Comment: yes its working... i am new to jquery .. now its getting betetr.
am using .get. 
btw wats the difference in jquery using get and post...?
php get post i know. can i get variables of a form using post with out submiting using jqueryposy?? asking foolishly!!!
am using get and its working now.

Comment: The GET and the POST, are the same in JQUERY and PHP, as it is independent from any language, it's part of the http protocol. Please see this link: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Answer (score 4):

You almost have it, you need to prevent the default action which is to follow the `href` in the link, so add either [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false`, like this:

```
$('a.pop').click(function(e) {                     //add e param
  var popID = $(this).attr('rel'),
      popURL = $(this).attr('href');
  $.get("content.php", { ref:id}, function(data) { //did you mean popID here?
    alert("Data Loaded: "+data ); 
  });
  e.preventDefault(); //or return false;           //prevent default action
});
```