# Change value of java variable using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

How can i change the value of java variable using javascript?

Suppose i have declare a variable in java servlet like `int x=0;`
so now i want to change its value to 1 on onclick event of any button on servlet how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE!** You should not hold state inside of your servlet, as it may be used by multiple threads (multiple users). Such values should be stored in the `Session` object, or in some backend - a database for instance.

Now back to your question: Your browser JavaScript code, cannot operate directly on Java code executing on the server. However, you could bind a `click` event handler to your buttons, and execute an AJAX call to your servlet increasing this value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611062/1344008) for an example of how to do it with JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change java variable using javascript, although you can do the other way round. Javascript is client side and java code in jsp page is executed on server side

Answer (score 1):

Can't change java variable's value from javascript.

but through java code we can change java script variables value.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant do that without sending a request at server, if you are ready to send the request then you can assign variable value in `<input>` value and send it in request OR Use `Ajax` to do so by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`JavaScript` executes at client side , and `Servlets` written in `Java` executes at server side.

Both are different environments. If you want to change the state of the server side object from `JavaScript`, you should be doing it through `AJAX`.

**Question:** Suppose i have declare a variable in java servlet like int x=0; so now i want to change its value to 1 on onclick event of any button on servlet how can i do that?

**Answer:** You should not have variable in Servlet. Because `Servlets are not Thread Safe.` I think you just want to change the state of the client, which might be stored as session.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the value of java variable using javascript directly . what you  can do fist get the javascript variable in request parameter by putting hidden filed or pass it to url and then get value using `rwquest.getParameter("field").

`Javascript runs on client browser so you can't get it directly.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why everyone is saying you cannot do this.

Of course you can. I have called java methods from javascript many times using Remote API in JavaScript. If for instance using Seam, you can do it like this: http://docs.jboss.com/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/remoting.html

Here the OP must find out which framework he wants to use, or which remoting technology that is best suited for OP

For instance, you call a java method that takes int as parameter, and you apply the value to the variable.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: That Remote API will internally make a server call.

Comment: Yes, and? OP never says he cannot make a server call