# Getting value of a text Feild for ajax request Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple rails form looks something like this

```
 <%= form_for :phrase, url: phrases_path do |f| %>
       <p>
        <%= f.label :"Enter Your Text" %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :text %>
      </p>
        <%= f.fields_for :order do |builder| %>
      <p>
        <%= builder.label :"ваш email" %><br />
        <%= builder.text_field :email %>
      </p>
  <% end %>
```

This form goes to the appropriate controller and in the controller depending on the value(text) of the text area performs some calculations to create a price and then save the order.

And it works just fine. But I have another requirement. Before submitting this application the user can click on a button(inserted somewhere between the form) to know the cost. As I said above the cost is calculated using text of the text_area and some logic present inside **some method**. I would like to implement the button. On clicking the button an ajax request is started, the value(text) of the text area is retrieved and the cost is calculated depending on **some method**. This calculated value is then shown on the page.

I know to start an ajax request and update the page. What I dont know is how to get the value of the text_area for the Ajax request. I cannot apply everything in javascript since the computation of cost requires **some method** which is ruby/rails dependent

Comment: Well, using Jquery you can read the input field values .. On button click, you will read the input the field value and then send the value using Ajax to the server, and then catch the response sent by the server and put it where you want to put it back.

Comment: Yes, but then how do i start ajax request from jquery?

Comment: check this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/3611062/2767755

Comment: the issue here is that once he gets the value ,he does not require any processing that depends on ruby code, present in a controller

Comment: You can do what asked by the link example. I don't understand where you got stuck.

Comment: Thankx man I figured it out